# How to create a template where multiple columns are there inside one column

Tags: marklogic

My requirement is to create a template (create schema, view, collection and columns in it) and insert xml documents in the Document database in Marklogic. We will then use Microsoft Power BI to query data from these views from Marklogic.

I know that we can create a simple template file which will have a structure of collection, rows and columns. But can we create template view which can have multiple columns under one column?

- If yes, can someone please provide me a code snippet of that template.
- If not, what is the alternative approach to define view of multiple column data in Marklogic if this cannot be done in a template?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you provided a minimal example of the columns and some sample data to demonstrate what you have and the desired output.

Comment: The sample XML file looks like this - 
```<ns9:DocumentHeader>
  <ns9:DocRef>TEST</ns9:DocRef>
  <ns9:DocCreateDt>2021-02-21T18:51:43.2644278Z</ns9:DocCreateDt>
  <ns9:DocModified>TEST</ns9:DocModified>
  <ns9:DocModifiedDt>2021-02-21T18:51:58.3422988Z</ns9:DocModifiedDt>
  <ns9:Version>
   <ns9:CurrentVersion>
    <ns9:User>System</ns9:User>
                   </ns9:CurrentVersion>
                   </ns9:Version>
<ns9:DocumentHeader>
```
And they will have each columns ingested in Marklogic

Comment: What I want to understand is , by template we can create a structure of the data file (probably when the file type is csv ) . The same template driven approach can be followed for the XML file too if it has complexType elements and a hierarchy of elements?

Comment: What do you want the rows to look like?

Comment: I have one xsd suppose main.xsd where multiple fragments of xsds are imported . So consider a xml file generated from the main.xsd where multiple xml fragments are present which are actually from multiple xsds.
My doubt is - 

How I can arrange those data in the Marklogic view ? 
Do I have to create separate views for separate xsd fragments ? 
And if yes , then will those be embedded in one template ?